# HTML-form does not post back anymore after post with content-disposition

Tags: php, post, content-disposition

I don't know if it is a feature by design or something that I do wrong.

On a webpage I have a HTML-form which after a post back generates a PDF-document. This document is provided via as content-disposition. The idea was that the current page remains operation and the user can continue with its work.
But after a post back the PDF-document is provided as download, the current page stays in the browser. But the form does not post back another time.

In the form some input fields have to be filled in to be inserted in the document.

Technical order:
1) HTML form -> post
2) PHP request -> handle post and deliver PDF-document as download
3) page is browser remains the same, but does not post back anymore

Is this behavior by design or do I do something wrong in the PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was something of my own.
On the page a script was loaded which disabled all submit buttons after they where pressed to prevent multiple post backs.

So no weird feature of bug, but a own made problem.